# Setting Eclipse target platform using command line

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, target-platform

I know how to add and set a target platform in eclipse. But I'm trying to do the same thing via command line, i.e specifying the target platform via command line options. I tried setting "base location" property while launching eclipse,

```
   > eclipse.exe -vmargs -DbaseLocation="path to the plugins root folder"
```

as suggested in [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/eclipse-pune-dev/sBDi1XZ-wr0). I looked at the baseLocation property details [here](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/reference/pde_builder_config.htm). But this is not working. Please let me know the right way of setting target platform through command line.

Comment: The 'baseLocation' is only used when using the headless build, is that what you are doing?

Comment: @greg-449, I'm not doing a build here, but just launching eclipse via command line and I want to specify the target platform (the plugins) via command line while launching. Can you let me know if there is any other command line option using which I can specify this?

Answer (score 1):

There is no command line option to change the target platform when starting Eclipse. The 'baseLocation' is only used when running the headless build.

Changing the target platform is an expensive operation since it requires a full build, this may be why there is no command argument.

All Eclipse command line arguments and system properties are listed in the help [here](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fruntime-options.html)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Greg. I came across that link while googling, but thought if there was any other option so I asked. Now I'm looking at the API in 'org.eclipse.pde.core' plugin which has the ITargetPlatformService and other target platform api, now I'm trying to achieve the same programmatically (loading target platform through api). Many thanks for your pointers.

Comment: Did you manage to have success on that? We're creating a dev env with Docker and will be good to automatise the change of the Target Platform with our needs. Thanks